# avoiding mod() by exploiting overflow or using if statements

Tags: integer-overflow, modulo, arduino-c++

For my project I need to cycle through an array of values. The number of elements and values are chosen at compile time. Currently I use mod to cycle through these values in various different ways (i.e not necessarily a simple i++).

However, I look up the cost of mod() and it seems that its an expensive function in most architectures including atmega Arduinos and my application is time sensitive.

I've come up with two potential solutions, both with pitfalls.

- Overflow the index counter, exploiting that unsigned overflows to zero. This has the advantage of being very fast.
  Disadvantages: I need exactly as many array elements as there are, unique bytes - at least 256. Also, the code is difficult to re-read since most ppl wouldn't assume I overflow on purpose.
- An if statement that removes size_of_array whenever the index equals or exceeds it. The advantage is that size_of_array can whatever. Disadvantages: if statement is slower (how slow?).

In both situations edge cases that mod would deal correctly would not be encountered (i.e. taking the modulus of a very large number).

Are there any pitfalls to either solution that I have not thought of? Is there a better solution?

Comment: If the number of elements is a power of two, you can use bitwise AND instead of mod.

Comment: @melpomene, I think this is a good answer for my specific case, since I can choose the number of elements, and a generalization of my first solution. I'm also interested for the general case for a fixed array, but I'll probably accept your solution if you write it up.